# Branches still have differences after merging

Tags: git

git version 1.7.7.4

I have two branches `development` and `testing`.

Originally `testing` was created from `development`.

I have only been working on `testing`. So now my `testing` branch has a lot of differences compared to `development`.

Because the `testing` now has my latest changes I want make `development` the same as testing.

So I did the following to merge them.

```
git checkout development
git merge -s recursive -Xtheirs testing
```

However, when I get the difference between the two branches. There are still a lot of differences.

So I decided to reset the `development` branch and try again by doing the following:

```
git merge testing
```

However, I still get the same differences.

If I try and merge again without reseting. I get `already up-to-date`.

Is there any way I can make the `development` branch the same as the `testing` branch?

Many thanks for any advice,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After merging `development` onto `testing`, `development` will gain all the changes from `testing` but `testing` will have none of the changes on `development`. The graph will look something like:

```
*   bc6339d - (HEAD, development) Merge branch 'testing'
|\
| * 588c9a3 - (testing) commit message
* | 2d484f2 - another commit
```

See that `testing` and `development` are on different revisions.

To merge them they have the same changes you could do:

```
git checkout development
git merge -Xtheirs testing
git checkout testing
git merge development
```

The graph should now look like:

```
*   bc6339d - (HEAD, testing, development) merge branch 'testing'
|\
| * 588c9a3 - commit message
* | 2d484f2 - another commit
```

If you want to keep them separate, do `git merge --no-ff development`.